# On Sum of Reciprocal Primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, logarithms, infinity

Let's use Euler's notation that involves:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}} = \ln{\infty}$$
And
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{p_k}} = \ln{\ln{\infty}}$$

Could we say that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{p_{2k}}} = \frac{\ln{\ln{\infty}}}{2}$$
? Why/why not?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the real meaning of this question?

Comment: @Alan To know if as we get to infinity, the sum of the primes of the form $p_{2k}$ equales the sum of the primes of the form $p_{2k+1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be understood, use modern notation, not Euler's.  I think what you're saying is

$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{n} &\sim \log(N)  \ \text{as}\ N \to \infty \cr
 \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{p_n} &\sim \log \log(N) \ \text{as}\ N \to \infty \cr}$$

Now since $p_{k+1} > p_k$
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^{2N+1} \dfrac{1}{p_n}\le \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{p_{2n}} \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \dfrac{1}{p_n}$$ 
and thus
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{p_{2n}} \sim \frac{\log \log(2N)}{2}
\sim \frac{\log \log(N)}{2} \ \text{as}\ N \to \infty $$